# java task manager show processes , services and user

Tags: service, process, taskmanager

I'm building a sort of a task manager that just show processes (apps ,background process), services running and users. I need some (non-GUI) pointers on where to start, and on ways it can be done.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far and such?

Comment: starting right now , going through some books and googling alot ,
reason i posted it before i started is becoz some pointers are always time saving ,